# jQuery Tabs CSS UI issue

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I am trying to add an icon to one of the tabs on my page, but this breaks all the other tabs, in that it shifts them up.

here is the site, http://khine.3b1.org/jquery/nested.html

What is the best way to push the two left tabs so that they are aligned correctly?

Thanks

Comment: It seems the height of the icon is 16px which is pushing the container down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.manage-tab .ui-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    height:12px;
}
```